# What should we consider to use either static linking and dynamic linking?

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking, static-linking

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Static linking vs dynamic linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking)
>   [C++ application - should I use static or dynamic linking for the libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095363/c-application-should-i-use-static-or-dynamic-linking-for-the-libraries)

What point we should take care before selecting static and dynamic linking?

Comment: You should provide more context, it's not clear what you are trying to link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static linking is used for libraries which are trivial and which needs to be linked in order to execute your binary.

dynamic linking is used when you can load library on demand and once task is done, you can unload it. To Apply patches or use updated versions, dynamic linking will be useful, if binary compatibility is taken care-off.

--
Cheers