# How to ensure linux/* includes are available to NDK build?

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk

I used this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10965262/3178688) to get an executable successfully building as part of my Android application. I then tried to add a header file:

```
#include <linux/mmc/ioctl.h>
```

And the compilation starting failing with:

```
jni/mmc.c:1:29: fatal error: linux/mmc/ioctl.h: No such file or directory
```

This seemed to have something to do with the target platform, as this file is present in `android-ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-*/usr/include/linux/mmc/ioctl.h` but not in earlier platforms. I tried changing my minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in my app's build.gradle to 21 to no avail. I also tried including `TARGET_PLATFORM=android-21` in my native code's Android.mk, also to no avail. How can I get the build system to see the `android-ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-*/usr/include/linux/mmc/ioctl.h` that is definitely there in my ndk?

Comment: I believe you're supposed to set `APP_PLATFORM` in Application.mk, not `TARGET_PLATFORM` in Android.mk. How that works with gradle, I don't know.

Comment: @Michael I tried adding an Application.mk to my working setup, with the one line specifying `APP_PLATFORM := android-21` ... it worked! Thanks! Add as an answer if you'd like.

Comment: what about : ```#include <sys/ioctl.h>```