# Unable to do AF_UNIX socket IPC in Android using NDK: Operation not permitted

Tags: android, sockets, android-ndk, ipc

I am attempting to use unix-domain sockets and am developing under the NDK. I am routinely receiving `Operation not permitted` errors for various actions related to trivial `AF_UNIX`/`SOCK_DGRAM` type IPC.

I am able to successfully `bind` both processes to a particular interface but am unable to either `connect` or `send`/`sendto` without getting the error mentioned above. The bound interfaces *do* appear on the file system if an appropriate `ls` is done in the specified directory. Also, each interface name is given explicit `other-read/write` access using `chmod` to prevent any permissions problems.

**Process A (Consumer):**

```
struct sockaddr_un local_addr;
int ctrl_fd;

/* Clean the structure and copy over our observable address */
bzero(&local_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
strncpy(local_addr.sun_path, local_sock_name, sizeof(local_sock_name));
local_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;

ctrl_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

bind(ctrl_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &local_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));

/* Associate with our path */
connect(ctrl_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &local_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));

while(1){
    recvLen = recv(ctrl_fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
}
```

**Process B (Producer):**

```
int sock_fd;
struct sockaddr_un dest_addr, local_addr;

/* Get our socket handle */
sock_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

/* Define where we are to connect */
bzero(&dest_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
strncpy(dest_addr.sun_path, dest_name, sizeof(dest_name));
dest_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;

/* Define who we are */
bzero(&local_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
strncpy(local_addr.sun_path, local_name, sizeof(local_name));
local_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;

/* Make a name for ourself */
bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &local_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));

/* Associate fd with remote address */
connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &dest_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));

while(1){
    sleep(10);
    send(sock_fd, "test", sizeof("test"), 0);
}
```

However, I have managed only to be denied by `Operation not permitted` on both `connect` and `send`. Additionally, I tried removing the `connect` call entirely and simply using `sendto`, but I get the same error.

**Note**: I have removed any error printing from the snippet for brevity. In the actual code I am determining these errors by checking the return values of each sys-call and doing a `strerror(errno)` to get the respective error message.

Comment: As a sanity test, try adding internet permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> (this tag is child of manifest tag.)

Comment: @Bram, as I am only in the testing phase of this functionality I have simply created two executables and pushed them to the device. In other words, these executables are independent of a Java layer, or anything else. I do not have I then start them from a shell. Could this be the problem? I just used the NDK compiler and have no notion of an application tied to them during this step

Comment: how did you solve the problem? I have a similar issue

Comment: This is forbidden on Android devices by SELinux.
Experiments like this are better done on an enginnering build of android or the emulator.

You *could* try it on an emulator with disabled SELinux `android-sdk/tools $ ./emulator -avd NAME -selinux permissive`

Comment: @sherrellbc : can you please share the JNI(c,c++) files for the scoket communication.Now iam trying to a application with socket IPC communication using JNI._