# How to build an executable for Android shell

Tags: android, c, shell, android-ndk, executable

Sometimes I need to run a command or script on my device, but they are not available or don't exist.

Can we add some additional commands to `Android` device's `shell`,
except those commands that are already available on it?

For example, add `screenrecord` command to my device (my device has `Android` API lower than 19), which this is unavailable on it.

I know how to get the list of available commands on the device with `adb shell`

```
adb shell ls /system/bin
```

but I want to add more custom commands and scripts, to do some special and work.

Is there any way to do it? Or it's impossible?

Comment: See the [official guide(s)](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/build), the answers here are outdated or unnecessarily complex. For the easiest method (one line compile, no build system), see [this](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

*The answer provides a sequence of steps for building an executable for `Android shell` through both `Eclipse` (outdated) and `Android Studio` (4.1+ by the time of this writing). The last includes `ndk-build` and `CMake`.*

---

### I. PREPARE SOURCE CODE

As an example consider `mycommand.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("My Command!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

### II. BUILD EXECUTABLE

### *Eclipse (might be outdated)*

In assumption that `NDK` location is set in `Eclipse`, create a new `Android Application Project` and do the following steps.

1. **Add native support**. Right click on the project in `Project Explorer` > `Android Tools` > `Add Native Support` > `Finish`
2. **Add source code**, i.e. put `mycommand.c` under `project_root`/`jni` folder.
3. **Edit [`Android.mk`](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html)** under `project_root`/`jni` as follows:

   ```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE     := mycommand
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := mycommand.c

   include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
   ```
4. **Create [`Application.mk`](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html)** * under the `project_root`/`jni` folder:

   ```
   APP_ABI := all
   ```
5. **Build executable** and find it under **`project_root/libs/<abi>/mycommand`**.

**Binaries for `all` supported CPU architectures are generated here. Use `adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo` to find out the CPU architecture and set `APP_ABI` as per [Supported ABIs](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa).*

---

### *Android Studio and ndk-build*

The steps are as follows.

1. **Add `mycommand.c`, `Android.mk`** (same as in the `Eclipse` section above) to the `/app/src/main/cpp` folder.
2. **Edit `build.gradle`**:

   ```
   android {
       ...
       defaultConfig {
           ...
           externalNativeBuild {
               ndkBuild {
                   targets "mycommand"
                   // use a specific ABI filter if needed
                   // abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
               }
           }
       }
       externalNativeBuild {
           ndkBuild {
               path "src/main/cpp/Android.mk"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Build project** and find the executable under `/app/.externalNativeBuild/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/<abi>/mycommand`

---

### *Android Studio and CMake*

1. Create a project using the *Native C++* template.
2. **Add `mycommand.c`** to the `/app/src/main/cpp` folder and **edit `CMakeLists.txt`**:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION x.x.x)

   add_executable(mycommand
                  mycommand.c )
   ```
3. **Edit `build.gradle`**:

   ```
   android {
       ...
       defaultConfig {
           ...
           externalNativeBuild {
               cmake {
                   targets "mycommand"
                   // use a specific ABI filter if needed
                   // abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
               }
           }
       }
       ...
       externalNativeBuild {
           cmake {
               path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. **Build project** and find the executable under `/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/<abi>/mycommand`

---

### III. PUSH BINARY INTO DEVICE

Push `mycommand` binary from where it is located into your device. Keep in mind that files on SD card aren't executable by default, so the binary should be pushed into the device's internal storage. Depending of whether device is rooted or not you have the following options:

- On **non-rooted** device you can push the binary to **`/data/local/tmp`**:

  ```
   adb push mycommand /data/local/tmp
  ```
- On **rooted** device you can push the binary to SD card and then copy it to `/system/bin` (after remounting the partition in read-write mode) along with the other executable files:

  ```
   adb push mycommand /path/to/sdcard
   adb shell
   su
   mount -o rw,remount /system
   cp /path/to/sdcard/mycommand /system/bin
  ```

---

### IV. SET EXECUTABLE PERMISSION (*optional*)

Set the permission of the binary to be executable (*this might not be needed in case of `/data/local/tmp`*). Below `chmod 555`(r-xr-xr-x) is used:

```
adb shell chmod 555 /path/to/mycommand
```

---

### V. RUN COMMAND

Now you can shell into your device (with `adb shell`) and execute the command.

- On **non-rooted** device use the absolute path to the command:

  ```
   $ /data/local/tmp/mycommand
   My Command!
  ```
- On **rooted** device, in case the binary has been copied to `/system/bin`, you can call it by the file name:

  ```
   $ mycommand
   My Command!
  ```

Comment: On the step 3, you could run `adb root && adb remount`, which should simplify things, especially for the recent Android releases

Comment: Ok. I created and empty project., added `mycommand.c` and `Android.mk` to the `cpp` folder I created in `app/src/main/` and edited `build.gradle` by simply adding what recommanded (for the ndk case in it) and then make build apk. The build failed with the following error :

Comment: "Could not find method android() for arguments [build_4wbyjnnxfo36n8uu8rkjatpia$_run_closure1@332ef9dd] on root project 'MyConsoleApplication4' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. Currently in Android Studio you should choose _Native C++_ template located on the _Phone and Tablet_ tab (scroll down to the template).

Comment: Currently the _Android-Studio-with-CMake_ part of the answer is up-to-date.

Comment: Any example without android studio? I need flag for build because i got error `TLS segment is underaligned`

Comment: Is it possible to package the built exeutable binaries automatically inside an app's module? Like in assets folder or so?

Answer (score 3):

In case you dont have binaries at this location for **Android and ndk-build**, they are at

`app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\obj\local\arm64-v8a\objs-debug\test1`

for arm64-v8a and corresponding for other platforms.

Answer (score 2):

If in case you are getting this error:

*error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported* when you created the executable using *CMake*,

add these lines to app gradle

```
default config
{
..........
..........
externalNativeBuild
{
 cmake 
  { 
   targets "my_command"
   abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
   arguments "-DANDROID_PIE=ON" //important
  }
 }
...........
}
```