# Android: run a script on non-rooted device

Tags: android, shell, adb

Can I run my binary executable file or script bash file on a non-rooted device?
I have a small script like this:

```
#helloworld.sh
echo "hello world"
```

I saved it in `/sdcard` and try to run, but i got *"Permission denied"*. I have researched, the reason is Execute permissions on the `SDCard` is blocked.

Is it possible to run? How can I do that  without `SU` command? I think it is very helpful if somehow can execute any script file.

Comment: If you don't have execute permissions, you could try to open a shell (`adb shell`) and try `chmod 777 /path/to/helloworld.sh`. I'm not sure if you can do that on a non-rooted device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, I can run my script without SU permission, just use sh command:

```
$ cd /sdcard
$ sh helloworld.sh
hello world
```

I think we cannot do the same with a binary executable file.

Comment: For executing a binary [How to add more commands to Android Shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231168/how-to-add-more-commands-to-android-shell) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

On non-rooted device you can run a script on `SDcard` with `sh` command:

```
    adb shell sh path_to_script_on_sdcard/script.sh
```

Comment: the first portion of your command "adb shell" tells me you are running from a PC correct? How can I run the script.sh from the Android device? what do I need? is there an adb.exe in Android 11 OS? I need to run a bunch of "adb shell pm uninstall packagename"  among other things, assume device rooted not connect to a PC. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For a shell script you can setup [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) or [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) in your phone, enable Storage permission for it, launch it and than run the script like this:

```
sh PATH_TO_FILE
```

Replace PATH with the path of file under /sdcard. It should work.

To run a compatible binary, move the file from sdcard into Termux's home using:

```
mv PATH_TO_FILE $HOME
```

Then verify and enable, using `chmod +x $HOME/FILENAME` if necessary, the executable permission on that moved file and run it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a computer to attach [`adb`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) on device, try out this app:
https://github.com/jarhot1992/Remote-ADB

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.superadb

But it have some ad popups after several commands executed.