# Is it possible to run batch files in Android?

Tags: android, shell, batch-file, cmd, sh

Is it possible to run `batch/bat` file in *Android*?
Or is there any app to run it?

I hope there is some app what can run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean a Windows batch file, then no, as Android is not Windows.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to run `batch/bat` file in *Android*? Or is there any app to run it?

No, in *Linux*(*Android*) it's called a [script file](http://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-script.php), the one with the `.sh` extension (optional) ... Dig in [this direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36078987/android-run-script-bash-file-in-non-rooted-devices/36086217#36086217).

Reference: [SO Android shell script questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android%20sh?mode=all)

Answer (score 1):

you can by installing the dosbox app on android

Answer (score 0):

You can run the batch file using an Android dosbox player.
Download afreebox and then run the dos. In there you can change the file exploring directory to the folder where the batch file is located. And type the batch file name with ending of .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

You can run shell commands in android using termux and also run batch files alternative '.sh' which because in Linux (Android) it's called as script file, not batch file like windows '.bat'.