# Android: Why doesn't native binary have access to the internet, while my Android application does

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I importing a native binary that is started from an Android application that was done as more or less described in:
[Compile and use ABI-dependent executable binaries in Android with Android Studio 2.2 and CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917297/compile-and-use-abi-dependent-executable-binaries-in-android-with-android-studio)

Then I start the binary with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`

The problem is that the binary cannot access the internet, while the Java application can. To compare:

```
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 nu.nl");
```

works `(returns 0)`, while ...

```
res = system("/system/bin/ping -c nu.nl");
```

...doesn't work, it returns 512 (which is supposed to be right-bit-shifted with 8, which means ping returns the exit code 2)

Why doesn't this work?

Obviously the manifest file contains:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

Comment: `which ping` doesn't use internet, but if you install **ping** within your app, it won't be on the path. To run this ping in the context if your app, `Runtime.exec()` must provide full path to the executable

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong line. `res = system("/system/bin/ping -c nu.nl");` gives the 512 result (while `which ping` returns 0)

Comment: I updated my original question

Comment: The edited question is even more confusing. When you run **ping** with implicit path, it's still the system binary, not the one you embedded in your APK.

Comment: @AlexCohn Why would I ship my own ping if there is a system one already? Am I not allowed to use that one? The situation is quite simple: if the Java calls ping it can connect, if the native C app calls ping, it cannot connect.

Comment: Now your question makes more sense, still `/system/bin/ping -c nu.nl` fails for me, it's missing the **count**. `/system/bin/ping -c 1 nu.nl` seems to work.

Comment: @AlexCohn DOOHH! That was embarrassing,.. I guess that is why we shouldn't review our own code,..right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, I made an embarrassing typo in the C code,..

```
/system/bin/ping -c nu.nl
```

should have been

```
/system/bin/ping -c 1 nu.nl
```

(I did have connection problems as pointed out by a linked in curl library, but now curl isn't complaining about that anymore)