# Compile executable binaries with Android Studio 2.3.3 and CMake

Tags: android, cmake, addition, executable

I'm testing out the new Android Studio C/C++ building via CMake through stable gradle (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/external-c-builds).

In my app, an already rooted device needs to use an ABI-dependent binary that I compile inside Android Studio.

When I try to compile a standard executable file with

```
add_executable(mybinary src/main/cpp/mybinary.cpp)
```

binaries are generated inside the build folder:

```
app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi/mybinary
```

but they do not seem to be a  executable binaries file

```
file  app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi/mybinary
mybinary: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked
```

Which is the correct way to handle this need? Is a gradle-task the way to go?

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.zhy.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                targets "mybinary"
                abiFilters 'armeabi'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
    # For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )


add_executable(mybinary src/main/cpp/mybinary.cpp)
target_link_libraries( mybinary native-lib)
target_include_directories (mybinary PUBLIC src/main/cpp/mybinary.h})
```

I followed this topic,but not  correct:
[Compile and use ABI-dependent executable binaries in Android with Android Studio 2.2 and CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917297/compile-and-use-abi-dependent-executable-binaries-in-android-with-android-studio)

Comment: [Building executables for Android shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35275134/3290339)