# Custom library path for binaries included in Android app

Tags: android, linux, shared-libraries, library-path

I need to deploy a native binary executable in an Android app. My approach is mostly modeled after [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38930608/2703209). The build process differs, but I deploy the native binaries as assets, which the app copies to its internal private storage as needed.

I have taken further inspiration from Termux and am building a mini directory structure in private shared storage. The executable resides in `usr/bin`. However, it also depends on a library, which lives in `usr/lib`.

I use the standard Java mechanism of `ProcessBuilder` to start my binary. However, I figure I somehow need to tell Android where to look for the library required by the executable.

How can I tell Android where to look for libraries? Moreover, how can I ensure that my custom path takes precedence over system-wide library paths just in case there is a system-wide library which has the same name but is incompatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library path is set through the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. Sample code here (`context` can be any context you can get hold of, such as an activity, service or the application context):

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(context.getFilesDir()
    + "/usr/bin/mybinary --version");
builder.environment().put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", context.getFilesDir()
    + "/usr/lib");
builder.environment().put("PATH", context.getFilesDir()
    + "/usr/bin:" + builder.environment().get(Const.ENV_PATH));
Process process = builder.start();
```