# how to start or execute an EXECUTABLE app from Java apk or ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, executable

I can't modify init.rc or init.target.rc, so I want to start or execute an EXECUTABLE app(under like system/bin/) from Java apk or ndk.
So how to do it? Is there any API available?

Comment: [Building executables for Android shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35275134/3290339)

Answer (score 1):

[`Runtime.exec()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])) is a common way to start child process from java. In native code you may use [`system()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) or combination of `fork()` and `exec()`.