# gradle + ndkbuild + android studio 2.2 how to set supported ABIs?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, abi

I want to use android studio integration with ndkbuild.

My "native" part of project build only for armeabi-v7a-hard and x86,
and all works fine if I just run `ndk-build` in jni directory.
I have proper lines in `Application.mk`:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a-hard x86
```

To integration project into android studio I added such lines into `build.gradle`:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/lib/jni/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

But for some reason `gradle build` try build native code with `APP_ABI=armeabi` and failed, because of my code can only be build with `armeabi-v7a-hard`.

So how can I tell gradle to build my code only for `armeabi-v7a-hard` and `x86`,
or just not ignore `APP_ABI` line from `Application.mk`?

I try such variant:

```
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
      abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a-hard'
    }
}
```

but `gradle` failed with such message:

> ABIs [armeabi-v7a-hard] are not available for platform and will be
>   excluded from building and packaging. Available ABIs are [armeabi,
>   armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64, mips, mips64].

Note, that I use ndk 10, not last one (ndk 13), where there is `armeabi-v7a-hard`, and `ndk.dir` in `local.properties` to right value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35275134/3290339

Answer (score 1):

Link provided by @Titan is all you need to set the ABI.

The reason why it might not be working is because `armeabi-v7a-hard` is deprecated in 2015, so targeting it is resulting in this issue. You should target `armeabi-v7a` as per this [this post](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/353e653824b79c43b948429870d0abeedebde386/docs/HardFloatAbi.md)