# Binaries for Android

Tags: android, compilation, hardware, executable

Do I have to server different binaries for different Hardwares on Android* ?

For Windows I "have to" provide a 32 bit version and a 64 bit version. Do I need to do something similar for Android or is there only on hardware specification or something like that. Sorry for the wording of this question, it's because I do not have much knowledge about this topic.

Comment: [Building executables for Android shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35275134/3290339)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a pure java application, with no usage of the NDK, your application is compiled to an interpreted byte-code which isn't device dependent, so you only need a single version.