# Android/Linux native executable

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-studio, executable

I have C++ code for *Android* in an *Android Studio* project and want to add a *Linux* native executable in C++ that shares most of the existing C++ code. So there must be 3 subprojects (I think): *Android*, *Linux* and a library with the shared code.

Are there any examples how to do it?

Comment: No sorry, this is not helpful, cause an Android executable is build, but I want Android and Linux (Desktop) executable. The Android code exists, now I want to add a Linux subproject. (BTW I do not know if _subproject_ is the right term)

Comment: I don't know what in my text leads you to this assumption? I wrote 3 subprojects (or modules), one for Android, one for desktop Linux and one for the code both projects share.

Now I have for Linux a module. Gradle builds it (command line), but Android Studio ignores it. No solution found yet!

Comment: [Building executables for Android shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35275134/3290339)