# Running executable from Android shell

Tags: android, shell, executable

I copied my executable file to *Android* '/data/local/tmp' directory using

```
adb push /home/build/bin/myexec /data/local/tmp
```

I then changed the permission of the executable

```
chmod 755 myexec
```

When I tried  `./myexec`

I got this `/system/bin/sh: myexec: not found`

I understand that it is not working because it is not on the system's `bin` folder. Is it possible to run executable through the *Android*'s shell or through an *Android* app?

Comment: There is no need to `chmod` an executable under `/data/local/tmp`. Files under the directory are world-executable. If you used the full path to the file, i.e. `/data/local/tmp/myexec`, and it wasn't working, the problem probably is with the executable itself. What error message do you get in this case? Was it you who compiled the executable? If not, it might not fit to your device's CPU. If so, [Building executables for Android shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35231168/3290339) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If running the executable with a full path to it doesn't work, the problem might be with the executable itself, meaning it either

- wasn't successfully compiled, or
- was compiled for another [CPU](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa), not the one your device had.

In this case the options you have are as follows:

- if you have access to the source code, [compile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35231168/3290339) it for your device's ABI,
- if it is a 3rd party executable, ask for an executable compiled for your device's ABI (or, if possible, find it yourself).

Comment: checking device ABI with command `adb shell getprop | grep abi`. Not sure checking executable architecture: `file <filename-to-check>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use full executable path

```
/data/local/tmp/myexec
```

Or change directory first:

```
cd /data/local/tmp/
./myexec
```

Comment: I tried both and still not working