# Android does not see the executable file

Tags: android, c, arm, executable

I wrote a simple program in C that displays the string. I compiled it for the ARM architect and sent it via FTP to my rooted Leagoo M5.
I mounted the memory as RW and moved the program to /data/local.
I used 'chmod + x armexe' to add execute attributes. Despite this, after executing './armexe' the message './sh: ./data/local/armexe: No drunk file or directory' pops up.

This section from the terminal probably shows it best:

```
root@M5:/data/local # ls && ./armexe
armexe
tmp
sush: ./armexe: No such file or directory
```

This error seems strange to me, and somehow I could not find the answer to other forums.
Sorry for my English. I hope you understood me :)

Comment: I've seen "no such file" errors before on ARM when the ELF file format was bad: i.e., wrong processor type, wrong float type, wrong ABI, etc. There are lots of different ways to compile ARM code, and you have to pick the right one. No, I'm not sure which one your version of Android uses. It also might be compiled to look for a .so that isn't there.

Comment: Also the ld.so specified in ELF might be missed

Comment: [How to build an executable for Android shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35231168/3290339)