# How to Execute an executable file in android App?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, android-debug

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
 printf("Helloworld");
 return 0;
}
```

Normal C code that prints Helloworld.

I have to make an app to run this c code on a device running in android without using NDK and output Helloworld displayed in TextView.How to execute this?

Comment: You may need `adb shell`. But for `TextView` without NDK? Not a good idea.

Comment: Compile your program on android using "C4droid - C/C++ compiler & IDE".

Maybe you can try to modify and use something else than printf. Maybe use a function that changes a strings value that TextView uses.

Comment: @Maximus Thanks for reply,C4droid - C/C++ compiler & IDE is the android application,i have to write my own app to execute this code.

Comment: [How to build an executable for Android shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35275134/3290339)