# use android.mk rather then gradle in android studio

Tags: android

How can I force android studio to use android.mk rather then using gradle plugins, So my files have only android.mk and app.mk I can get output with ndk tools-build command but I need to do it with android studio itself?

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: In Gradle you should use `externalNativeBuild{ }`. For details you might look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35275134/3290339) answer (under _"Android Studio and ndk-build"_ section).

Comment: i cant get an output from this project which is a startwizard proje

Comment: I don't get you

Comment: i need to convert build gradle files to android.mk&app.mk

Comment: Then I think it'd be easier to use Eclipse