# Compiling GRPC's CSharp extensions with NDK for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-ndk

I am attempting to use GRPC with Unity. I'm stuck compiling a `libgrpc_csharp_ext.so` file which will successfully work with the `arm-v7a` Android archetecture. I expected the following command to work from the GRPC repository root:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -I. -I./include -fPIC -o libgrpc_csharp_ext.o -c src/csharp/ext/grpc_csharp_ext.c
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -I. -I./include -shared libgrpc_csharp_ext.o -o libgrpc_csharp_ext.so
```

I cobbled this together from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798357/want-to-compile-native-android-binary-i-can-run-in-terminal-on-the-phone). It compiles successfully and Unity recognizes the file when placed in `/Plugins/Android` as a `arvm7` library:

[image]

but when GRPC attempts to `DllImport("grpc_csharp_ext")` on an actual Android device, I get an error:

> Unable to load library
>   '/data/app/PACKAGE/lib/arm/libgrpc_csharp_ext.so',
>   native render plugin support disabled: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "grpc_slice_from_copied_buffer"
>   referenced by
>   "/data/app/PACKAGE/lib/arm/libgrpc_csharp_ext.so"...

Followed by:

`Unable to find grpc_csharp_ext`

I know this is possible because [this](https://github.com/neuecc/MagicOnion) open-source project has successfully cross-compiled the necessary files. When I download the .so file from their project and drop it into mine [it successfully loads](https://github.com/neuecc/MagicOnion/tree/master/src/MagicOnion.Client.Unity/Assets/Scripts/gRPC/Native/Android/arm-v7a), except it was compiled with a very old version of GRPC and I therefore do not wish to use it. Furthermore, I've already [successfully created an .a file for iOS](http://examinedself.com/cross-compile-grpc-unity/) which works well with a similar strategy. When I check my file with `file libgrpc_csharp_ext.so` I see that it is `ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/bin/linker, with debug_info, not stripped`. This matches the type of the file obtained from the open-source repository.

It seems like the appropriate symbols are not included in the resulting `.so`, based upon the error message above and also that the `.so` is ~36kb, but the "correct" `.so` from the open-source project is >5mb. I guess I'm compiling a dynamic library that doesn't include all the necessary symbols, but I'm not enough of a compiler guru to find the correct options.

Comment: Based on offline discussion, it seems you've solve the issue. Can you update this post so others can benefit from your experience?

Comment: Done; working on commiting my fork now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of the GRPC team, I have a working solution; see my comment in the issue here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/14402#issuecomment-369942250

I'm working with them to hopefully get this integrated into master. In the mean time, I will try to keep this blog post up to date with the instructions for each platform (not just Android): http://examinedself.com/cross-compile-grpc-unity/