# Android shell don't find the file to execute

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, adb, cross-compiling

I compiled a code of hello world in `C` through `gcc` for ARM. I uploaded the resulting binary to my device and I tried to run it through `adb shell`. First I got an error about permissions and fixed that. Now it gives me the `file not found` error but I can see the file in the `ls` output.

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/q/10798357/1778421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your executable is missing a library. The most likely reason is that you just built a Linux ARM executable (not an Android one) which is linked against some `libc` version other than Android Bionic.

You could either learn how to build proper Android executables or a statically linked binary might just work for your purpose.

Comment: The only library there is stdio.h, I tried to link it statically using the --static argument and also the weight has increased, 8 kb before and 500 after, but I get the same error.

Comment: I do not want to compile it with the android libraries, I want to use static libraries in such a way that the application is also compatible with linux arm devices.