# Is it possible to replace the default libc.so by embedding a custom one in an Android App?

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, shared-libraries

The Android system provides a default **libc.so**, and it will be loaded automatically in every app.

Now I just want to change the **libc.so**'s function `abs()`, say, I want `abs(any_number)` always returns 0; and the other functions are same as the original **libc.so**'s.

The easiest way is modifying the `abs()` function body of `libc` project, and rebuilding the modified project. The output is also named **libc.so**, and embedded in the APK.

Is this way possible?

The Android App launcher will first load the embedded **libc.so** if any?

Comment: "Is this way possible?" -- I highly doubt it. The zygote process will have already loaded `libc` at boot time, and app processes are forked off of the zygote. "it will be loaded automatically in every app" -- no, it is automatically loaded by the zygote.

Comment: Yes it's quite possible, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10395889/192373